# Pyspark: Update dataframe column values with values from another row's columns, based on a condition, where the rows have a like column value

Tags: pyspark

I have a requirement to update column values in one row with values from another row.  This would only be done if a specific condition occurs.  The other row would be found by matching on a column that has an identical value.

Consider this data:

| ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | SUBS_NO | BILL_NO | ADDRESS | CITY | STATE | ZIP | RELATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SMITH | JIM | 123 | 123 | 123 MAIN ST | SOMEWHERE | WI | 12345 | 1 |
| 2 | DOE | SALLY | 456 | 456 | 456 ELM AVE | ANYWHERE | AZ | 54321 | 1 |
| 3 | SMITH | JANE | 123 | 789 | 888 3RD ST | SOMEWHERE | WI | 12345 | 2 |

Condition: Anytime we encounter a row that contains a RELATION <> '1', we need to get column values from the row that has the same SUBS_NO of the current row.  In this case, we'd replace the LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, BILL_NO, and ADDRESS.

The end result should be:

| ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | SUBS_NO | BILL_NO | ADDRESS | CITY | STATE | ZIP | RELATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SMITH | JIM | 123 | 123 | 123 MAIN ST | SOMEWHERE | WI | 12345 | 1 |
| 2 | DOE | SALLY | 456 | 456 | 456 ELM AVE | ANYWHERE | AZ | 54321 | 1 |
| 3 | SMITH | JIM | 123 | 123 | 123 MAIN ST | SOMEWHERE | WI | 12345 | 2 |

How would I go about accomplishing this in Pyspark?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
w0=Window.partitionBy(col("SUBS_NO")).orderBy(col("RELATION"))
df_new=df.withColumn("FIRST_NAME",when(col("RELATION")!=1,lag(col("FIRST_NAME")).over(w0)).otherwise(col("FIRST_NAME")))
df_new=df_new.withColumn("LAST_NAME",when(col("RELATION")!=1,lag(col("LAST_NAME")).over(w0)).otherwise(col("LAST_NAME")))
df_new=df_new.withColumn("ADDRESS",when(col("RELATION")!=1,lag(col("ADDRESS")).over(w0)).otherwise(col("ADDRESS")))
df_new.show()
```

Comment: This works great!  Thank you.  There's one exception.  How would you update duplicates?  Meaning, John Smith has 2 Jane Smith's that have his same 'SUBS_NO'?

This method updates the 1st Jane Smith, but not the 2nd.

Comment: @CraigLarson, please give an example with dummy data frames of this scenario. I think you mean thatt there could be more than two repititions

Comment: That's correct.  I know now what's occurring.  Since lag only gets the previous row's values, if we encounter another row where RELATION !=1, but the SUBS_NO is the same the as the previous 2 rows, nothing happens.  That's because previous row's RELATION was also not equal to 1.  So yes, if we have more than 1 row where the RELATION is not 1 and the SUBS_NO equals the previous rows, it does not update.